# CSS body:after not displaying

Tags: css

In order to show a parallax effect on Safari on iPad, I have adopted the following CSS rule:

```
body:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(https://www.batteryminerals.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/F8A7576-e1520920156360.jpg) center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can see this effect on [this site](https://www.batteryminerals.com) (behind the "current projects" section).

The corresponding [staging site](http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au) has the CSS rule:

```
body.home:after{
    content:"";
    position:fixed; /* stretch a fixed position to the whole screen */
    top:0;
    height:100vh; /* fix for mobile browser address bar appearing disappearing */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1; /* needed to keep in the background */
    background: url('http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/F8A7576-e1520920156360.jpg') center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

in [this file](http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au/wp-content/themes/wtc%2029.3.18/styles/wtc.style.css).

It also has the inline `<style>`:

```
<style>
    body:after{
        content:"";
        position:fixed; /* stretch a fixed position to the whole screen */
        top:0;
        height:100vh; /* fix for mobile browser address bar appearing disappearing */
        left:0;
        right:0;
        z-index:-1; /* needed to keep in the background */
        background: url('http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/F8A7576-e1520920156360.jpg') center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

on line 531.

However, the background image does not display at the staging site.

If I look in Chrome code inspector, on the production site, I see:

```
        ::after
     </body>
</html>
```

but on the staging site, I don't see that ::after in code inspector.

Can you see why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got your solution:

Just Add `display:block` in css and it's work:

```
body.home:after{
    content:"";
    position:fixed; /* stretch a fixed position to the whole screen */
    top:0;
    height:100vh; /* fix for mobile browser address bar appearing disappearing */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1; /* needed to keep in the background */
    background: url('http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/F8A7576-e1520920156360.jpg') center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you Minal. I don't know why the production site gets away without the `display: block`.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear about the issue, `display:block` **isn't mandatory** to make the `:after` element showing:

```css
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url(https://www.batteryminerals.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/F8A7576-e1520920156360.jpg) center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But the real issue is that you have some other CSS applied to your pseudo element that set display to none, so you are obliged to override this style by setting `display:block`

[image]